# Finding the nearest grid box to a point in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, grid, latitude-longitude, nearest-neighbor

I'm using MATLAB to to analyze model data.

Right now, I'm dealing with latitude, longitude, and altitude data. Both latitude and longitude are matrices of 336 x 264 and their output is in units of degrees. My altitude data is 3 dimensional. The first two dimensions are latitude and longitude and therefore 336x264. The third dimension is the altitude layer and therefore a number 1->27 based on the height at the point. The output is in meters, but I've converted it to centimeters and assigned it to the variable "gridh".

---

For my code I'm starting at the origin and moving in a direction one cm at a time until I hit the top of the atmosphere like so:

```
gridh(:,:,:) = h(:,:,:,12); % Convert to 3d matrix at noon
origin = [lat(168, 132) lon(168, 132) 0];
theta  = 90; % Zenith
theta_rad = degtorad(theta); % Convert to radians
psi = 0 ; % Azimuth
psi_rad = degtorad(psi); % Convert to radians

s = latlonstepcm ;% Degrees % will also be used for altitude, but will convert this back to altitude in cm later.

dx = s*sin(theta_rad)*cos(psi_rad) ;% Change in lon
dy = s*sin(theta_rad)*cos(psi_rad); % Change in lat
dz = s*cos(theta_rad) ;% Change in altitude
dz_cm = dz*(1/(9e-08)) % converting dz to cm cm

dxf = origin(1) + dx;
dyf = origin(2) + dy;
dzf = origin(3) + dz;

position_final = [dxf dyf dz_cm]
```

The origin is just some point in format [lat lon altitude] like this: [ 26.19 degrees, 26.19 degrees 0 cm]

I'm trying to move at the specified changes in direction until all the way through the grid and at every cm interval (or more, I don't really care if the interval is different I just want the concept correct) I want to check the grid box so I can multiple the grid box by the average no2 amount within the assigned grid box.

So basically, I want to find the gridbox that

```
    position_final = [dxf dyf dz_cm]
```

is in and then mulyiply the amount of no2 in that gridbox

```
 no2_moleccm3(?,?,?,12)
```

by the 1 cm distance traveled through it.

Hopefully this makes sense!

I'm fairly stumped, I've been trying this for a while.

---

If someone could help me with the lat-lon alone, I know that using if statements I can identify the layer in the z direction easily, so maybe that will lessen the difficulty here?

Thank you

Taylor